# Catch when minimize button was pressed on any window

Tags: c#, windows

So I'm trying to make window manager that could minimize windows into something like Facebook Messenger chatheads. For that i need to catch minimize event on any window that is open when my program starts, or will be opened later. And that's the tricky part, at least for me. The only way I could think of was global hooks, but as far as I know, they are only applied to windows that are currently opened and not the ones that will open later, which means i would have to actively look for any new windows and hook into their wndproc too which would be performace heavy. Also as I was reading about hooks, I found that it's discouraged to use them as they rather heavily impact performance.
So my question is what is the best way to catch minimize events?

Thanks in advance,
Ignas

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  If you are trying to make something that could minimize windows, then you need to *send* minimize events, not *catch* minimize events.

Comment: Basic idea is user clicks on minimize button, window disappears and instead of window something like Messenger chathead appears that you can toss around the screen or click on it to bring window back. I'm sorry if I was unclear, hopefully this clear things up a little bit more

Comment: In this case, you are looking for "window procedure subclassing", and your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364152/handling-messages-for-window-from-other-process

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks